# Como capturar o texto que um outro programa de console escreve na tela

Tags: c#, winforms, console

Meu programa de Windows Forms executa outro programa de console. Esse segundo escreve mensagens na tela durante a execução. Eu quero saber se tem como impedir que a execução do outro programa abra o console, e em vez disso, os printf do outro programa (que é escrito em C++) sejam exibidos no meu TextBox.

Exemplo prático: o Imagex é um programa de console da Microsoft. Um usuário criou o Gimagex que tem interface gráfica e executa o Imagex e todas as saídas de texto aparecem no Gimagex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de fazer `process.Start()` coloque `true` em `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` e `false` em `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute`

Supondo que quer receber o *output* do programa *ConsoleApplication.exe* numa *ListBox* faça assim:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartProcess();
}

public void StartProcess()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleApplication.exe";
    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);

    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
}

private void OutputHandler(object process, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data);
    }
}
```

<sub>**Nota:** Parto do principio de que *ConsoleApplication.exe* não necessita de qualquer intervenção(input) do usuário ao longo da sua execução.</sub>

Fontes:
[ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Process.BeginOutputReadLine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Nesse seu esquema o console ainda abre mas sem texto, mas o problema é que na linha que passa o texto para meu TextBox (que se chama "Saida") gera a exceção: `Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'Saida' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.`. E sim, o executável de console não necessita de intervenção do usuário.

Comment: Abrir o console é mesmo assim. Em relação ao problema dos *thread* se você está a executar o meu código noutra *thread* não poderá aceder a nenhum componente visual. Use um [*Task* juntamente com um *IProgress*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx)