# Meu programa tá com problema de desempenho

Tags: c#

Eu fiz esse programa com a ajuda do usuário ramaral. Ele é um programa Windows Forms e tem que executar um outro de console. A questão é que eu preciso que em vez desse outro programa abrir o console, ele fique oculto (sem janela do CMD) e meu programa capture os textos que o outro escreveria na tela.

Do jeito que tá agora, ele está abrindo a janela do console (sem texto nenhum) e o meu demora muito tempo pra exibir os textos capturados e perde alguns deles no processo, sendo que o aplicativo de console não faz nada além de escrever mensagens de 50 a 100 linhas no total.

Obs.: O aplicativo de console não precisa de intervenção do usuário.

```
// Esse método que inicia todo o processo
private void Confirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Saida.Text = "Linha de comando: VboxManage " +
    this.Parametros.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    Process processo = new Process();
    processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processo.StartInfo.FileName = this.VBox;
    processo.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InsercaoNaTela);

    processo.Start();
    processo.BeginOutputReadLine();
    processo.WaitForExit();
    processo.Close();
}

// Essa é o evento que acontece quando o aplicativo de console escreve algo na tela
private void InsercaoNaTela(object obj, DataReceivedEventArgs Texto)
{
    this.Tarefa = new Thread(FuncaoTarefa);

    // Não sei se tem como usar um método com parâmetros,
    // então eu uso um atributo da classe.
    // Texto.Data é o texto capturado do console
    this.Externa = Texto.Data;
    this.Tarefa.Start();
}
public delegate void Delegado(String Testo);
public Delegado Delegar;
private Thread Tarefa;
private string Externa;

public void Adicionar(String Texto)
{
    // Finalmente a Thread principal escreve o texto capturado no meu TextBox
    this.Saida.Text += Texto;
}

private void FuncaoTarefa()
{
    // Invoca o delegado passando o texto como parâmetro
    // Que eu saiba tem que usar um delegado pra alterar
    // controles criados por outras Threads
    this.Invoke(this.Delegar, new Object[] { this.Externa });
}
```

Comment: Lá na outra [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74003/2541), quando li o seu comentário, pensei que o problema era outro. Agora que postou o seu código ficou claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O programa demora muito a apresentar os dados porque fica bloqueado à espera que o outro termine.

Faça assim:

```
// Esse método que inicia todo o processo
private void Confirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Saida.Text = "Linha de comando: VboxManage " +
    this.Parametros.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

    //Inicia o outro programa em outra thread
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartProcess(this.VBox));

}

//Método que inicia outro processo
public void StartProcess(string fileName)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);

    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
}

// Essa é o evento que acontece quando o aplicativo de console escreve algo na tela
private void OutputHandler(object process, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        //Invoca a main thread para actualizar o TextBox
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            this.Saida.Text += e.Data;
        }));
    }
}
```